# Getting last related record(s) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've been looking for the best method to do this quite some time with mediocre results so I decided to ask here.

The scenario is as follows: I have three models, Task, User and Comment, that essentially look like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :comments
end
```

I'm trying to output a list of tasks (let's say last 10 for the purpose of this question), and associated **last comment** for each task and it's author (user model) with **the least queries possible**.

Thank you

**UPDATE**: I've combined solutions by Blue Smith and harigopal so the solution looks like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_one :last_comment, -> { order 'created_at' }, class_name: "Comment"
end
```

and then fetch comments like this:

```
tasks = Task.joins(last_comment: :user)
  .includes(last_comment: :user)
  .order('tasks.created_at DESC').limit(10).load
```

which produces **only one query**, which was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think I'm being understood correctly, so I'm posting further explanation with this comment: It's not the limit of tasks that I'm concerned with, the number is completely irrelevant, I'm trying to somehow to simulate the scenario, where task would only have **one comment** so the question is how to **eager load last associated comment**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to join the tables, and eager-load the data to minimize number of queries.

For example:

```rb
tasks = Task.joins(comments: :user)
  .includes(comments: :user)
  .order('tasks.created_at DESC')
  .limit(10).load

comments = tasks.first.comments   # No query, eager-loaded
user = comments.first.user        # No query, eager-loaded
```

This should reduce the number of queries to **just one** (very complex one), so you'll have to make sure your indexing is up to snuff! :-D

Official documentation about combining joins and includes is vague, but should help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations

**EDIT:**

Here's a demo application with the same models as yours performing eager-loading using the above method. It uses **two queries** to load the data. Fire up the app to see it in action.

https://github.com/harigopal/activerecord-join-eager-loading

Comment: This produces: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "task"

Comment: I've updated the solution with a demo application (SQLite3). Try it out.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong somewhere but when I tried something similar, I had a LEFT OUTER JOIN for comments and it was loading all the comments, not only 10, so if you have 10 tasks and each of those has 10,000 comments, you're in trouble

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
class Task
  scope :recent, order('created_at desc')
  scope :last, lambda{|n| limit: n }
end
```

Now you have reusable scopes:

```
Task.recent.last(10)
```

And i'm guessing you want to output the last 10 tasks for a given user (let's say the current logged in user).

```
current_user.tasks.recent.last(10).includes(comments: user)
```

Comment: Do not use `scope` with lambdas with parameters. Use class methods instead.

Comment: Because [the preffered way](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) is to use class methods.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but Lukasz isn't the preferred way also using lamdas, but in the   -> form instead of the older lamba form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_one :last_comment, :class_name => 'Comment', :order => 'comments.created_at DESC'
end

@tasks = Task.limit(10).includes(:last_comment => :user)
```

`last_comment` is a "virtual" association and just load only one `Comment` record. The advantage of this approach is that it will use less memory (because just load one `Comment` and one related `User`). If you use `includes(comments: user)` it may consume a lot of memory (if there a lot of comments :).

Comment: Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :as, :touch (ArgumentError)